# How to use definitions stored in a DB to definitions in your source code?

Tags: database, enums, definition

I would like to get some ideas how to use definitions which are stored in a DB (which is used by your application) into the source code of the application.

Example:

**Database**

- Cars
- CarTypeDefinitions

A column of `Cars` links by a foreign key to a row in `CarTypeDefinitions`, therefore defines the type of the car which is contained in `Cars`.

`Cars` contains entries like *'Aston Martin DB8'*, *'Range Rover'* and *'Mercedes Actros'*.

`CarTypeDefinitions` contains entries like *'Sports car'*, *'SUV'* and *'Truck'*.

**Source code**

Now I would like to be able to use these definitions in my source code as well. So somehow we need to create some kind of mapping between a row in the `CarTypeDefinitions` table and a (preferably) type-safe implementation in the source code.

**One possible implementation**

The first thing which comes to my mind (and I am especially looking for other solutions or feedback on this one) would be to create an `Enum` `ECarTypeDefinitions`.

```
public enum ECarTypeDefinitions
{
    SportsCar = 1,
    SUV = 2,
    Truck = 3
}
```

Now that we have a type-safe `Enum` we can use it e.g. like this:

```
public bool IsSportsCar(Car currentCar)
{
    return (currentCar.CarType == ECarTypeDefinitions.SportsCar);
}
```

The contents of that enum would be auto-generated from the contents of the `CarTypeDefinitions` table (add two additional columns for name of the enum and its integer value).

This would also work the other way, e.g. generate the content of the `CarTypeDefinitions` DB table from the `ECarTypeDefinitions` `Enum`.

I'm keen to hear about other ways how to tackle this problem. How have you dealt with this?

Comment: What you're describing is essentially [object relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping). I'd suggest starting from provided link and then digging deeper, eventually finding out what ORM you'd want to use with a language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. We're already using Entity Framework 4.0 with C# in our application development. While EF generates the objects for us to use (e.g. `CarTypeDefinition`) we still need to have some kind of mapping or how would you know that a particular instance of a `CarTypeDefinition` object describes a sports car?

Answer (score 0):

I do it the way you have suggested. Some others prefer to combine all constants into a "Lookup" table. You can look at an example of some of the pros and cons here: http://weblogs.foxite.com/andykramek/archive/2009/05/10/8419.aspx

Edit: Here's a thought that may help spark further ideas from you.

Create a class for each Car Type:

```
public class SportsCarType
{
}
```

Now add an attribute to CarTypeDefinition:

```
public class CarTypeDefinition
{
    ...
    public string typeName;
}
```

Populate the new attribute (for each type you have) using typeof:

```
...
carTypeDefinition.typeName = typeof(SportsCarType).Name;
...
```

Finally your new IsSportsCar method:

```
public bool IsSportsCar(Car currentCar)
{
    return (currentCar.CarType.typeName == typeof(SportsCarType).Name);
}
```

I'm not familiar with Entity Framework so perhaps it has a way to allow this kind of thing to be more cleanly done. Also a little rusty on C#.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way how to do it without the enums? I was just discussing this with a colleague earlier and we couldn't get to a conclusion on this question.